# Redirect URL non existent subfolder to root

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I have moved my site from www.site.com/shop/ subfolder to root. Now the "**shop**" folder doesn't exist anymore and I would like to redirect people who still go to site.com/shop/whateverhtml to site.com/whateverhtml 
I have tried different Rewrite rules but with no luck.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop/.*
RewriteRule shop/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

or like this

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/shop/$ http://site.com/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/shop(/.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^shop(/.*)?$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: None of the above rules work. I still get the 404 page not found when going from a cached link from google (with "shop" folder in link) to the actual link

Comment: Both of them are working by me... Maybe you have multiviews on, or another htaccess overrides these, I don't know...

Comment: I notice that the rewrite rule works if I add the subfolder in the link. It means it's because google cached the site with the "shop" folder in links and changed the link's name. I guess I have to wait for Google to re cache the site...

Answer (score 0):

**Redirecting**

This requires you make an empty `shop` folder.
In the folder, create an HTML file called `index.html`. Users will be directed here when visiting `http://site.com/shop`.
In that file, put this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://site.com/">
</head>
<body>
You are being redirected...
</body>
</html>
```

This will redirect them to `http://site.com/`.

**Framing**

You can show another page on the page with an `<iframe>`. An `<iframe>` shows another page, within the same page, without redirecting. You still have to keep the shop folder. In it, put index.html with this content:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Shop</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://site.com/"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

This will create a page with an iframe of site.com

Comment: i'm trying to keep the uri the same not just to redirect them to the new site. like site.com/shop/folder1/page.html to site.com/folder1/page.html

Comment: In that case, you could use an `<iframe>`.