# Nginx redirection from any subfolder to root index.html

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

Anything put as a subfolder, it will read the domain.com/index.html

Similar to this but in Nginx
[Redirect URL non existent subfolder to root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127961/redirect-url-non-existent-subfolder-to-root)

Answer (score 0):

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.com;
    root /apt/website/path;
    index index.html;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```